# Extract row and column indexes of 0s in binary image in Numpy

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

So, I have a binarised grayscale image and i want all the x,y points of 0 (dark pixel) in the image.

```
image = np.random.rand(30,70)
binary = image > 0.70 #thresholding 
points = np.asarray(np.where(bin == False))
points = points.reshape(-1,2)
pl.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
pl.scatter(p[:,0],p[:,1])
pl.show()
```

i am extracting all the indices (x,y coord) in this image where there is 0 or False using `np.where` but it is not working. Here is the output which is very strange.

[image: output]

Shouldnt it be the blue dots on top of the black pixels? Also why is the blue points outside the dimensions (30*70)?

It seems very simple problem with unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing your variable names (`binary` and `points`, not `bin` and `p`), the only problems I see are that you've done `points = points.reshape(-1,2)` for no obvious reason (mixing up the coordinates) and that imshowing `image` and scattering `points` will have incompatible orientations.  Something like

```
image = np.random.rand(30,70)
binary = image > 0.70 #thresholding 
points = np.asarray(np.where(binary == False))
pl.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
pl.scatter(points[1],points[0])
```

should give
[image: gray and dotted image]

Comment: The reason i am using `points = points.reshape(-1,2)` is making it 2d array to feed the k-means clustering algorithm. i want to generate 2 clusters.